# Why does this program not work? It returns "dinner" for both (12,true) and (7,False) and i dont get why

Tags: python-2.7

```
def food(var1, var2):
    var2= bool(var2)
    if var1<6:
        food1 = "no food"
    else:
        if (6<var1<11) and (var2==1):
            food1 = "breakfast,marmalade"
        else:
            food1 = "breakfast,coffee"
            if (12<var1<16) and (var2 == 1):
                food1 = "lunch,dessert"
            else:
                food1 = "lunch"
                if (17<var1<22) and (var2 ==1):
                    food1 = "dinner,dessert"
                else:
                    food1 = "dinner"
                    if (22<var1):
                        food1 = "no food"
    return food1
```

Comment: if you run through the logic in your head for (7,False) you see it will end up setting food1="dinner" because it is catching pretty much all the else statements

Answer (score 0):

Both inputs fall to the last else. In the first case you should have 
17<=var1<=22 and in the second you should have var2 == True

Comment: Thanks i figured it out, i alternated the truth values of the if/else statements and put an elif statement to prevent the first one falling through